# logging in libcurl

Tags: libcurl

How to modify libcurl so that all the error descriptions are collected in a common log file ?
I am trying to port libcurl to android and display curl logs on adb. Is there a way to log all the activities of libcurl ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply using [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTDEBUGFUNCTION)? It was designed for exactly such a purpose...